# How do i make all rows of pytest-html single html report result file default to a collapsed state?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-html

I use the pytest runner to get the output of results from my automated test frameworks (Selenium and RestAPI tests). I use the pytest-html plugin to generate a single page html result file at the end of the test. I initiate the test run with the following command (from an active VirtEnv session).

`python -m pytest -v --html="api_name_test.html" --self-contained-html`

(it's a little more complicated in that I use a powershell script to run this and provide a datetime stamped result file name and email the file when it's finished but it's essentially the above command)

When the reports are generated and I open this report html I find that all the non passing tests are expanded. I want to make it so all rows are collapsed by default (Failed, XFailed, Error etc..).

[image: html result with some files expanded]

My project contains a conftest.py file at the diretory root and a pytest.ini file where I specify the directory for the test scripts

In the conftest.py file in my simplest projects, I have one optional hook to obtain the target url of the tests and put that in the report summary:

```
import pytest
from py._xmlgen import html
import os
import rootdir_ref
import simplejson

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_summary(prefix):
    theRootDir = os.path.dirname(rootdir_ref.__file__)
    credentials_path = os.path.join(theRootDir, 'TestDataFiles', 'API_Credentials.txt')
    target_url = simplejson.load(open(credentials_path)).get('base_url')
    prefix.extend([html.p("Testing against URL: " + target_url)])
```

The Github page mentions that a display query can be used to collapse rows with various results, but it doesn't mention where this information is entered.
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html

"By default, all rows in the Results table will be expanded except those that have Passed. This behavior can be customized with a query parameter: ?collapsed=Passed,XFailed,Skipped"

Currently I'm unsure if the `?collapsed=...` line goes in the command line, or the conftest as a hook, or do I need to edit the default style.css or main.js  that comes with the pytest-html plugin? (Also i'm not familiar with css and only know a small amount of html). I'm assuming it goes in the conftest.py file as a hook but don't really understand how to apply it.

Comment: The query parameter is passed to the generated HTML report, so e.g. when you open it in browser, use the URL `file:///path/to/report.html?collapsed=Passed,XFailed,Skipped`. This is something you can't adapt from the hooks because [the collapsing of test blocks is handled entirely in `main.js`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/master/pytest_html/resources/main.js#L84). The only way I see is to replace the `main.js` file with the one without the `if (collapsed.includes(elem.innerHTML))` check.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @hoefling , I couldn’t find anywhere that indicated how to use that option. I’ll try experimenting with the JS file and see if I can make it do what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#display-options

Auto Collapsing Table Rows

By default, all rows in the Results table will be expanded except those that have Passed.

This behavior can be customized either with a query parameter: ?collapsed=Passed,XFailed,Skipped or by setting the render_collapsed in a configuration file (pytest.ini, setup.cfg, etc).

[pytest]
render_collapsed = True

NOTE: Setting render_collapsed will, unlike the query parameter, affect all statuses.

Comment: Thanks @john the pytest.ini render_collapsed option is good to know. The document you provided a link to, still doesn't mention which file one actually puts the ?collapsed parameter in, which was the basis of my confusion when I asked the question.

Comment: @Roochiedoor
 
Add it in pytest.ini file, or any pytest config files.

[pytest] 
render_collapsed = True

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @john answer and the other steps I have tried:

For some reason,

```
[pytest]
render_collapsed = failed,error
```

Does not work for me, based on the steps here:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#configuration-file-formats

When using the above configuration, I get the following error:
KeyError: 'render_collapsed'
ValueError: invalid truth value 'failed,error'

To resolve the issue:
Create a Configuration file on the directory where you will run the command.
In my case I use pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
render_collapsed = True
```

Then run:
`pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html`

`report.html` is the name of the report file

`--self-contained-html` creates the report with inline css. This will allows you to simply share the `report.html` file instead of sharing a folder containing html and css files

More information about other Configuration file formats(pytest.ini, pyproject.toml, tox.ini, setup.cfg) can be found here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#configuration-file-formats